# WebStorm ghost breakpoint

Tags: debugging, webstorm, breakpoints

Sometimes my WebStorm hits a nonexistent breakpoint and it's pretty annoying.
[image]

I'd tried to delete all of them without success. 
The only thing that works is restarting the IDE, that's the "annoying" part.

Is there some trick to fix it faster ?

My Webstorm version is 2016.2.3
I don't have a test case to accomplish this situation, but it happens more frequently when I'm using the Live Edit functionality and editing the code while the IDE is already stoped into a breakpoint even when I wait for the "reload script" message.

Comment: do you add/remove breakpoints while debugging? Breakpoints deleted during debug session are not cleared, debugger still hits them; you have to restart the debug session to have then cleared.

Comment: 2023 and this is still a problem even in new versions!